# Typescript: Extend interface with generic interface

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

Let's say I have interface:

```
interface IAddress {
    addressProperty: any;
}
```

Is there a way to write interface similar to this:

```
interface ILoadable<T> {
    loading: boolean;
}
```

So I can use it like:

```
interface IStateSlice {
    address: ILoadable<IAddress>;
}
```

Where address will be ILoadable extended with IAddress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
interface IAddress {
    addressProperty: any;
}

interface ILoadable {
    loading: boolean;
}

interface IStateSlice {
    address: ILoadable & IAddress
}
```

and then use it:

```
class StateSlice implements IStateSlice{
    address = {
        loading: false,
        addressProperty: 'lol'
    }
}
```

You can also define a separate type for that:

```
type LoadableAddress = ILoadable & IAddress

interface IStateSlice {
    address: LoadableAddress
}
```

or same, using interface extending

```
interface LoadableAddress extends ILoadable, IAddress { }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thx! I never thought that you can use `&` this way :D

Comment: You can also do multiple implements separating them by comma. In addition you can extend multiple interfaces the same way, so you can create a class that extends both interlaces

Comment: @Kindzoku, then you can mark this answer as selected )